# New keyword used with Interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, new-operator

Although I've looked through several of the answers regarding this question, I'm still not sure if I know what this line of code is doing:

```
public class SomeClass<P> : SomeInterface where P : AnotherInterface, new(){...}
```

What is `new()` doing?

Comment: `new()` says that `P` must be a type which has a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

While you usually see `where T : Whatever[, Whatever2]` refer to other interfaces and classes, it can also be one of any of [these constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

- `where T : struct` - T has to be a value type
- `where T : class` - T has to be a reference type
- `where T : unmanaged` - T and all of its variables have to be value types, as well as the variables those value types have... etc.
- `where T : new()` - T has to have a parameterless constructor.  This constraint must be specified last.
- `where T : U` - T must be or derive from the argument supplied for U

Comment: In case you're wondering, yes this allows you to call `new T()` in your interface's code (or `new P()` in your example).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! The [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) you refer to really explain it nicely. @Powerford - yeah,I should have used T instead of P...